Excess part from integration of graph
Photo of Graph of a arbitrary function on which integration is performed 
Here, in the photo, using the basic idea of integration, we make a long rectangular block to cover the area under the graph. But in the process, there is some excess part of the rectangle outside the graph.
How can we approximate the excess part for a significantly large area?
And How do we remove the area of the excess part from our answer?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Right_rule
